# How can I SUMIF a cell if another cell matches a cell on multiple pages?

Tags: excel

What I am trying to do is set up a total value of a cell that is associated with a particular shop on multiple pages.

I have 20 different sheets of products for instance.

I want to sum cell I2 if cell H2 is the same on my formula sheet's B13.

I have `sheet1:sheet20!H2` has to be the same as `total!B13`(the sheet where the formula is) and I am summing the value of `sheet1:sheet20!I2`

In my logic I wrote this:

```
=SUMIF(SHEET1:SHEET20!H2,B13,SHEET1:SHEET20!I2)
```

But sadly, my logic doesn't seem to give an answer.

`B12` will have the sum of all the `I2` cells throughout the 20 sheets.
`B13` would have the shop name "Shop Y" for example.
`SHEET1:SHEET20!H2` on the individual sheets will also have that shop name "Shop Y".
`SHEET1:SHEET20!I2` will have how much money was spent at "Shop Y"

And then this will sum up all money spent at Shop Y on various products through the 20 sheets.

Then I will do the same for Shop X etc (but this will just need a copy and paste).

Comment: unfortunately, SUMIF isn't one of the functions that support 3-D references. List of supported functions under **Create a 3-D reference**: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f. Looks like you'll have to some additional helper cells

Answer (score 2):

`=SUM(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,Sheet1:Sheet20!H2:I2)&"</b></a>","//b[preceding::*[1]="""&total!B13&"""]"))`

The part

`"<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,Sheet1:Sheet20!H2:I2)&"</b></a>"`

creates a string whose delimited substrings comprise the entries from `Sheet1!H2`, `Sheet1!I2`, `Sheet2!H2`, `Sheet2!I2`, etc., in that order.

By passing this string to `FILTERXML` with an appropriate *xpath* parameter (which, in this case, checks whether the preceding entry in that delimited string is equal to the entry in `total!B13` or not), we obtain the desired sum.

This set-up could fail if the entry in `total!B13` were numeric. From your description, however, I assumed that this was not the case.

Comment: I have to say, Jos, you are amazing and I genuinely don't have a clue how you have done that. You showed something similar on a previous sheet of mine too. But I admit, I equally don't understand what or how you came up with this. I also don't understand how MS haven't made what seems like an easy fix to something we can do regularly!

Comment: I have to agree with you, Paul. To be fair, right now we're witnessing a genuine and long overdue reworking of the extensiveness and capability of Excel functions. That said, for whatever reason, three-dimensional, multi-sheet querying has been sadly neglected for the time being. Cheers.